# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

First of all, I would like to say that i really didn't want to ask this question, but after two hours of not understanding the reason of it, it now decide to ask for some help.

I want to add the ngResource module in my app. Before doing it, everything worked well.

So I create my app like this :

```
var app = angular.module('app', [ 'ngResource', 'ngRoute'  ]);
```

then i config it like this :

```
app.config(
    [
        '$resourceProvider',
        '$routeProvider',
        '$locationProvider',
        function ($resourceProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider ) {

            $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                controller: 'homeController'
            }).when('/404', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/404.html'
            }).otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/404'
            });
        }
    ]);
```

And i get this error which means :

```
Failed to instantiate module app due to:
TypeError: Cannot set property 'stripTrailingSlashes' of undefined
at http://localhost:3000/js/app.js:14 


This error occurs when a module fails to load due to some exception. The error message above should provide additional context.
```

line 14 is of course :

```
 $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
```

The angular-resource.js is well loaded and before app.js.

I don't understand, I did it exactly like it's said on the Angular Doc :(

I hope my question isn't completely stupid and the reason is not obvious cause I really don't see where I am wrong!

Thank you if you can help me !

Bastien

Comment: Have you tried to debug it in Chrome dev tools? If you add a breakpoint on the $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false; line is the $resourceProvider populated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ability to configure stripping of traling slashes was added in **AngularJS 1.3.0-beta.6**.

Make sure you are not using an earlier version.

The changelog of AngularJS can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: After searching in the doc, I don't find where it is explicit :s

Comment: Don't be sorry for asking questions :) If you mean you can't find it in the changelog search for 3878be52.